# What does one call words or phrases that cannot be or rarely refered to with kanji

Tags: phrases, rōmaji

I have found that many words are only used in hiragana and because of this i can't seem to find a good way to learn them as i am studying words that use kanji due to the site i am using. Like-ごめんなさい, そうか, etc. are these type of words given a type of name?

Comment: I think you have a typo -- rather than ごめんあさい, I think you mean ごめんなさい?

Comment: I think you also wrote "romaji" where you meant to write either "kana" or "hiragana" (though it isn't actually true that 御免{ごめん} is always written in kana).

Comment: It’s not exactly an answer, but if you use the search term “かな書き” in the 明鏡 dictionary (using the 全文 functionality), you will get a nice list of words that are usually written using kana (because it matches the “【表記】かな書きが多い” note in the entries).

Comment: There are two kinds of such words. (Recent, non-Chinese) loanwords do not have _kanji_ at all (or rather artificially through _atemi_). Some words historically had _kanji_ which are seldom used today.

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge, there is no term that specifically means "word usually written in kana". In modern standard Japanese, Western-origin loanwords are almost always written in katakana. Particles, adverbs and interjections tend to be written in hiragana. Learning words based only on kanji may not be a good idea because of this.